# Topological vs algebraic intersection forms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, quadratic-forms, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a simply connected complex projective surface (hence a real $4$-manifold). Let $(H^2(X,\mathbb Z)/\mathrm{tors}, q_X)$, $(A^1(X)/\mathrm{tors},q_X')$ be the corresponding lattices in cohomology and intersection theory, where $q_X$ and $q_X'$ are the intersection (bilinear) forms $q'_X(V,W)=\deg(V\cdot W)$, $q_X(\alpha,\beta)=(\alpha\cup\beta)\cap[X]$.

There is a cycle map

$$\gamma:A^1(X)\to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\cap H^{1,1}(X)\subseteq H^2(X,\mathbb R)$$

Let $(A,q')$ be the lattice $(A^1(X)_{/\mathrm{tors}},q'_X)$, and let $(H,q'')$ be the lattice $(H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\cap H^{1,1}(X),q_X|_{H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\cap H^{1,1}(X)})$.

Is there an example of $X$ for which the two lattices $(A,q')$ and $(H,q'')$ are not equivalent? (Does answering depend on the Hodge conjecture in this case?)

Comment: What definition of $A^1(X)$ do you use?

Comment: I am confused by the first part of the question. Of course there are examples where the two lattices are not equivalent, since $A^1(X)$ (whatever definition you are using) only detects the algebraic part. Think of K3 surfaces, for instance, where the transcendental part of $H^2(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$ plays a key role. Am I missing something?

Comment: @abx: codim 1 cycles mod rational equivalence.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: I've edited the question a bit. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Yes, but this is completely standard: $\gamma$ is an isomorphism (Lefschetz theorem), and it is compatible with the bilinear forms (note that $A^1(X)=\operatorname{Pic}(X) $ has no torsion when $X$ is simply connected).

Comment: @abx: Ok, thank you. Should've posted on stackexchange.